# Finding all the names with a given surname in a file using sed

Tags: sed

For the given file with following input test, I want to out put all the names with surname Smith, I have done it using `grep`:

```
grep -o -w "[A-Za-z]* Smith" filename
```

But I want to know how it can be done using `sed`, I have tried

```
sed -e 's/[A-Za-z]* Smith/&/g'  filename
```

but it is printing the entire line.

Input files text :

```
John Smith Kent Smith Adam Smith
Adam Jones Devlin Thomas Bill Kate
Mark Taylor Dean Bush Kane King Nicole Smith
John Williams Adam Cole
James Brown Jason Taylor Mark Rose
Rache Davies Christian Williams
Chris Evans Steve Williams Craig Thomas Jack Smith
Jonna Wilson Jack Jones Jason Patt
Chris Thomas Connor Smith
Kat Watson Kat Smith Julia Roberts Greg Smith Bill Smith
Michael Johnson
```

Comment: Fwiw: `tr ' ' '\n' < input | paste -d' ' - - | grep ' Smith$'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this is not as easy as I thought it was, since `grep -o` shows each match on a separate line. If you want to use `sed` twice, you can say:

```
sed -e 's/\([A-Za-z]* Smith\)/\n\1/g'  names | sed '/Smith/!d'
```

Comment: Nope , this is not that I am looking for ,  Smith
Adam Jones Devlin Thomas Bill Kate
 Smith
John Williams Adam Cole
James Brown Jason Taylor Mark Rose
Rache Davies Christian Williams
 Smith
Jonna Wilson Jack Jones Jason Patt
 Smith
 Smith
Michael Johnson

Comment: Smith
Adam Jones Devlin Thomas Bill Kate
 Smith
John Williams Adam Cole
James Brown Jason Taylor Mark Rose
Rache Davies Christian Williams
 Smith
Jonna Wilson Jack Jones Jason Patt
 Smith
 Smith
Michael Johnson

Comment: Thanks Michaels, this is much easier with sed , I put one more \n  after \1 iin the replacement string  and it gave the corrrect answer     sed -e 's/\([A-Za-z]* Smith\)/\n\1\n/g' names | sed '/Smith/!d'

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sed '/[A-Za-z]* Smith/!d;s//\n&\n/;s/^[^\n]*\n//;P;D' file
```

**Explanations:**

- `/[A-Za-z]* Smith/!d`: retains only lines containing letters followed by `Smith`
- `s//\n&\n/`: adds a newline(`\n`) before and after first string matching above address pattern
- `s/^[^\n]*\n//`: removes unwanted strings(those not starting with `\n`)
- lines now only contains desired names with surrounding `\n` character on the first match we can loop on with multiline `P` and `D` commands that act as a loop on strings containing `\n` characters
- `P` prints the first part of the pattern space, up to the previously added newline character
- after printing, `D` deletes the same first part of the pattern space

For more about `P` and `D` that are part of the multiline commands, please read http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html.

But `grep` is definitely more suited for this job.

Comment: this works but I am struggling to understand it ,I got the first part     sed '/[A-Za-z]* Smith/!d  can you explain rest of the      part s//\n&\n/;s/^[^\n]*\n//;P;D'

Comment: to the input  when I do  sed '/[A-Za-z]* Smith/!d;s//\n&\n/'     it gives me  following as out put                                                              John Smith
 Kent Smith Adam Smith
Nicole Smith

Jack Smith

Connor Smith

Kat Smith
 Julia Roberts Greg Smith Bill Smith   so when we do sed '/[A-Za-z]* Smith/!d;s//\n&\n/;s/^[^\n]*\n//'  then why is the second line not removed  because it also does not start with a \n ?

Comment: the second line is:  Kent Smith Adam Smith

Comment: when I do ;P   Kent Smith Adam Smith  is still there but as soon as ;D is added  both the names are output in two new lines , did not understand all that , can you explain plz

Comment: The newline before `Kent Smith Adam Smith` is the one added to the end of `John Smith`, not a newline from the file. I strongly suggest you look at the link provided in answer. I'm not sure SO comments are the right place to discuss on sed subtleties :-)

Comment: You see both names after `P` without `D` because only one name is processed at a time(here `John Smith`. Remaining names will be added their newlines in next loop. `P` and `D` replaces the normal line by line  flow of sed. It's something you might have to work with a while before being familiar with.

Comment: I read the comment you gave in the answer and got a little idea , but still have some question that I would chase you for , like where does the sed loop start in you answer right at s//\n&\n/  ? if there is nothing in the search pattern of the sed syntax, does that mean it takes the previous pattern in the pattern space (here "[A-Za-z]* Smith"  in     sed '/[A-Za-z]* Smith/!d ) ?  I mean for s//\n&\n/  what is the search patttern ? Sorry if I am asking too much but am new to sed and this seems to be an advance topic.

Comment: and I have read the link also and got some idea about your solution

Comment: I mean if you could  explain the execution sequence of your answer for 2-3 input lines it would be useful for me to understand completely

Comment: It loops at the top of the script to eventually apply further `\n` inclusion if another string matches, until there is no more matching string hence no more `\n` for `P` and `D` to work with.

Comment: This schema might help : http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/sedawk/figs/sed_0601.gif.

Comment: okay so its like a script (not the command piping )  where ; is allowing sed to take multiple actions on the line read and when all the combined actions are taken on the read line  the script reads the next line and takes the same actions for the next line and thats how it loops through lines in the file ?

Comment: Yes, sed works line by line, it's the normal flow... that you can "break" using multiline (`N`, `P`, `D`,...) or branching commands (`b`, `t`, `T`).

Answer (score 1):

you didn't ask but...

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -v sur="Smith" '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) if($i==sur) print $(i-1),sur}'
```

file

```
John Smith
Kent Smith
Adam Smith
Nicole Smith
Jack Smith
Connor Smith
Kat Smith
Greg Smith
Bill Smith
```